# Why is $X\hat{\beta}$ regarded as $y$ in multiple linear regression while estimating sigma square?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

[image]

Screenshot from page 80 of the textbook "Introduction to Linear Regression Analysis" fifth edition by Douglas C. Montgomery

Let $X$ be $n \times p$, $y$ and $\hat{y}$ be $n \times 1,$ and $\hat{\beta}$ be $p \times 1$ matrix in the multiple linear regression model. From the matrix calculation, we can easily find $\hat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1}X'y$ and $\hat{y}=X\hat{\beta}$. However, in the later part of this chapter, the estimation of $\sigma^{2}$, while calculating the residual sum of squares, the textbook says $X'X\hat{\beta} = X'y$ which indicates $X\hat{\beta}=y$. But I don't understand why it is not $\hat{y}$. Can anyone answer this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X'X\hat{\beta} = X'X \left((X'X)^{-1}X'y\right)=\left(X'X (X'X)^{-1}\right)X'y=X'y$

This does not imply that $X\hat{\beta}=y$ though. In algebra, the statement $CA=CB$ only implies that $A=B$ if $C$ is invertible, and, in this case, $C=X'$ is not even (necessarily) a square matrix.

What it does imply, however, is that $X'y = X'\hat y$, which is true in general, since $X'e = X'y-X'X\hat \beta=0$.

---

Addendum:

If $X$ is a square matrix with full-rank ($n=p$), then $y=\hat y$.

Comment: Thank you for answering this question clearly. By the way, is it the typo in the first line that you wrote $X'y$ outside the bracket from $X'X((X'X)^{-1}X'y)X'y$? Would it be $X'X((X'X)^{-1}X'y)$?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that @user375779 :)

Comment: For a specific example, consider the case of a regression of $y$ on a constant, $X=\mathbf{1}$. Then $\hat\beta=\bar y$ and thus $X\hat\beta=\mathbf{1}\bar{y}$, the sample mean replicated into a vector of ones, which would only be equal to $y$ if $y$ always took the same value.